# Display an image from url in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I want to display an image from a URL in React. For example, I want this image

```
https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350
```

to be displayed in a Card body or reactJS. Is it possible to do it or do I have to download it to assets before I can display it? And how to do it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As you do in HTML

```
 import React from "react";
 import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

 function App() {
   return (
     <img 
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"
      alt="new"
      />
   );
 }

 const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Using this code I received the following error: 
`Error: img is a void element tag and must neither have children nor use dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: @SamuelRosenstein try [codeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-cray-ozp2l) to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 12):

To solve this;

**For local images**:

Use an import statement
*No need to pollute the public folder*

```
import slideImg1 from '../../assets/pexels-pixabay-259915.jpg';
```

Then use in Jsx like this

```
    const solveLocalImg = () => (
<img src={slideImg1}/>

//or

<div data-src={slideImg1}>
      </div>
)
```

**For online images**

*Use an array*

```
let imgs = [
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/stealthman22/image/upload/v1586308024/new-portfolio/hero/time-lapse-photography-of-waterfalls-during-sunset-210186.jpg',
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/stealthman22/image/upload/v1586308023/new-portfolio/hero/two-cargo-ships-sailing-near-city-2144905.jpg',
];

 const solveOnlineImg = () => (
<div>
<img src={imgs[0]}/>
<img src={imgs[1]}/>
</div>
)
```

You can use as many images as you like with the second method. It even makes it easy for you to manage your images.
Hopefully, soon enough we'd either get a solution that can make us do things how we are used to with just HTML CSS and js

For now, we are stuck with amazing Webpack

Answer (score 5):

You can use  tag for displaying the image.If the image source is in props/state use `<img src={this.props.url}/>`

Answer (score 3):

Yes. it is possible. just use `<img />` tag.

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
```

Answer (score 0):

In the App.js file, write following code:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  return(
    <div>
      <img src="image-url" alt="image" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's different between this answer and the accepted answer?

Comment: The accepted answer shows error (Error: img is a void element tag and must neither have children) which can be resolved by returning every thing inside a div container. It is also a good practice to return every thing as one entity.