# Display an image from url in ReactJS in tsx file

Tags: reactjs, image, networking, import, tsx

I want to display an image from a URL in React. For example, I want this image in tsx file

http://d1cs08zudd3ykv.cloudfront.net/dev/img/arrow-up.svg
to be displayed in reactJS. When I am trying to use requires not working but require is working with the local path. Is it possible to do or Is there any other way to do it? And how to do it?

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail. What have you tried so far? What code do you use to try and display the image?

Comment: There is question with almost the same name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184136/display-an-image-from-url-in-reactjs