# How to open a picture by link (<a></a>)?

Tags: reactjs

I have some text which I'd like to be clickable.
And I want the picture to be opened when I click the certain word in a new window (not in a new tab).
How could I do that? The code below does not work.

```
<p>Click on the <a href = "./images/TheForm.jpg">"Request Access"</a> button and fill in the form.</p>
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, check here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184136/display-an-image-from-url-in-reactjs/51184326

Comment: Here you find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132162/2828611

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `target="_blank"` to your link if you want to open the destination of a link in a new tab:

```
<a href = "./images/TheForm.jpg" target="_blank">Request Access</a>
```

And define a `onClick` method to open it in a window :

```
<a href="./images/TheForm.jpg"  
    onclick="window.open('./images/TheForm.jpg', 
                         'windowName', 
                         'width=800, height=600'); 
              return false;"
 >Request Access</a>
```

When you specify the width/height, it'll open the link in a new window instead of a tab.

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#position_and_size_features) for further information.

Comment: I wanna click on the text and open the pic in a new window (not tab).

Comment: @Anthony I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="IMAGE_URL" target="_blank">
  <img alt='img_path' class='img-40 rounded-circle' src='IMAGE_URL' />
</a>
```

Comment: I don't wanna make a link from the pic. I wanna click on the text and open the pic in a new window(not tab).

Comment: then you will need to use target="_blank" and the new tab is a new window what is the difference between tab and window?

Answer (score 0):

It's for react:
import CardImageOne from './Images/card-image-1.jpg' //Image source//

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).